# How do I replace a word in some text using CSS?

Tags: css

I have a third party plugin and I need to change a word. They only give me access to CSS:

```
<span class="apple">This is some words</span>
```

Changed to:

```
<span class="apple">This is some text</span>
```

How would I do that with pure CSS?

Comment: Not possible. You have to use JS

Comment: Is it possible to hide an element that contains a word I don't like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try as below using pseudo selector `:after`,

```css
span{
  position:relative;
  color:transparent;
}
span:after{
  content:'This is some text';
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  color:#111;
}
```

```html
<span class="apple">This is some words</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the HTML then you can hide the wrapper of the unwanted text:

```
p.old-text-class { diplay: none;}
```

And insert the new text at the same place in HTML:

```
<p class="new-text-class">This is some text</p>
```

Comment: Can I detect the text though with some selector though?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a pseudo element with content.

```css
.apple {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.apple:before {
  content: "This is NEW text";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<span class="apple">This is OLD text</span>
```

Comment: I see, so I can change content if I know where it is but there's no selector if content is dynamic in any way. I guess that answers my question thanks @Pangloss

Comment: @AmyNeville Correct, surprise to see you didn't pick this first and simpler answer, any reasons for why?